# How do I fix a broken font after adding anchors and changing ligature lookup names?

Tags: font-design

I changed the lookup table names for some ligatures and anchor classes and now the font is broken.  Is there a way to repair it?

I am using FontForge to edit an Arabic font.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Font Doctor](http://www.fontgear.net/fontdoctor.html). There are versions for both Mac and Windows. I don't know of anything that's as good for font repair.